# Swift event for when sectionheaders touch in an UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a function called when two section headers touch when scrolling through the uitableview?

Comment: Hi. There is no specific API event / delegate for that. It may be possible to trick around via `didScroll` event from UIScrollView and checking visible views (but not sure without testing ; and could break from one to another iOS version). Could you share what you would like doing?

Comment: Your question is to know when the section header of your tableView tapped?and what do you want to do when scrolling in tableView?Could you please provide more details about what you want to achieve??